# NodeJS Express app await is only valid in async function but this clearly is async function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

I have made a function to check if a certain thing already exists in the database. I have simply copy-pasted the logic I'm using to get something in the database and changed the query object + what is returned. But now it seems that node doesn't like that and just throws an error that makes no sense to me.

Where I call the function:

```
let exists = await queryDatabaseExists(uniqueQuery, res);
```

The function that I'm calling:

```
async function queryDatabaseExists(queryParam, res) {
    try {
        const cp = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
        await cp.connect();
        let result = await cp.request().query(queryParam);
        if(result.recordset.rowsAffected[0] = 1){return true} else { return false }
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(520).send(`Database error: ${err}`);
    }
}
```

The error that I'm getting:

```
let exists = await queryDatabaseExists(uniqueQuery, res);
             ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

ALL code for that route:

```
router.post("/admin/category", (req, res) => {

    uniqueQuery = `SELECT [name] from [dbo].[idtTV_categories] WHERE [name] = '${req.body.name}'`

    getQuery = `SELECT [id]
    ,[name]
    ,[description]
    ,[created_time]
    ,[created_by] from [dbo].[idtTV_categories]`

    standardQuery = `INSERT INTO [dbo].[idtTV_categories] ([name],[description],[created_time],[created_by]) 
    VALUES 
    ('${req.body.name}', 
    '${req.body.description}',
    SYSDATETIME(),
    '${req.user.name}')`;

    let exists = checkIfExists();

    function checkIfExists() { result = await queryDatabaseExists(uniqueQuery, res); return result} ;

    console.log(exists);

    if(req.user.roles.some(role => role === admin || role === editor)){
        if(!existsInDatabase){
        if(queryDatabase(standardQuery, res)){queryDatabase_get(getQuery, res)}
    }
}

    else { res.statusMessage = `${req.user.name} is not authorized to add categories.`;
           console.log(req.user.roles)
           res.status(520).send() };

})
```

All functions being called:

```
///////////// MAIN QUERYING FUNCTION //////////////////////
async function queryDatabase_get(queryParam, res) {
    try {
        const cp = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
        await cp.connect();
        let result = await cp.request().query(queryParam);
        res.send(result.recordset);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(520).send(`Database error: ${err}`);
    }
}

async function queryDatabaseExists(queryParam, res) {
    try {
        const cp = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
        await cp.connect();
        let result = await cp.request().query(queryParam);
        if(result.recordset.rowsAffected[0] = 1){return true} else { return false }
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(520).send();
    }
}

async function queryDatabase(queryParam, res) {
    try {
        const cp = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
        await cp.connect();
        let result = await cp.request().query(queryParam);
        if(result.rowsAffected > 0){ return true }
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(520).send(`Database error: ${err}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: is the function that this`let exists = await queryDatabaseExists(uniqueQuery, res);` is in async as well?

Comment: @AdamH I don't understand your question

Comment: You have the line `let exists ....` is that in a function?

Comment: no, I'm trying to store the result of the async function as a boolean;

Comment: most likely you defined the variable 'exists' inside some function that is not async. Make that function async and it should solve the issue.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm getting at.

Comment: @DanielVarela I've renamed that to gibberish and weird enough, I'm getting the exact same result. I'm also not trying to do anything else with it other than logging it on the console.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what Daniel and myself are asking. show us the code around `let exists = await .....`

Comment: @AdamH Probably am, I have added all code relevant to that route and the main functions for quering the database.

Comment: `router.post("/admin/category", (req, res) => {` should be `router.post("/admin/category", async (req, res) => {`

Comment: `function checkIfExists() { result = await query` should be `async function checkIfExists() { result = await query` as well

Comment: Basically, if you are using Async/Await then everything needs to be async or fall back to `.then` (consume the promise)

Comment: @AdamH But why is this necessary for checking if exists but is not necessary for the functions that query the database AND when I call the functions in other routes? This has started happening solely when I duplicated the main function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182515/discussion-between-adam-h-and-sebastiang).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it must be inside async.
ex:

```
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  let exists = await queryDatabaseExists(uniqueQuery, res);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, due to some issues with express I've ended up refactoring it differently and split my main quering function in a flow of 4 async functions so I don't have a mess in my routes. But your solution worked right off!

Answer (score 0):

This means that the function in which the call to queryDatabaseExists is performed must also be async, in order to use the await keyword inside it. The queryDatabaseExists function itself looks correct.

Comment: Hmm, I wanted to call the query and store the result (True or false) in that 'exists' variable and then run some code once that is performed. if I don't use await, it seems to just defautl to 'promise' and the rest of the code doesn't work. Should I wrap awaiting for the functions in a whole other function that just calls that function?

Comment: The premise of async/await is that you make all relevant functions async (or use the promise API as before in some parts of the app). Any reason you can't make the outer function async? Express supports it just fine

Comment: I tried to use `  let exists = checkIfExists();
    
    function checkIfExists() { result = await queryDatabaseExists(uniqueQuery, res); return result} ;

    console.log(exists);` Same result sadly. This is very weird now.

Comment: `function checkIfExists()` should be `async function checkIfExists()`

Comment: @AdamH Ok I did that but then when I try to define the variable I am hit with the same problem. If I don't await the result of that promise, exists is being used everywhere as Promise Pending. Then if I try to await THAT function, same  result on the console.

Comment: @SabastianG see my comment on your question

Answer (score 0):

queryDatabaseExists function need to return promise if not you cannot use await

await command expect a promise to be return by the function [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

```
let exists = await queryDatabaseExists(uniqueQuery, res);
```

Answer (score 0):

**await** can only be used in async function. For your scenario you wanted wait for result from uniquequery. First you have to make change in your router.post callback like **router.post('/url',async(req,res)=>{});** for making a synchornus call to **checkifexist** function. Second in order to use **await** in checkifexist function you have to make changes to checkisexist function to **async function checkifexist(){}**. Thirdly you wanted to wait for DB response for that you have use **await** while calling checkifexist function --> **let result=await checkifexist()**. you can check MDN website for better understanding.

```
router.post('url',async(req,res)=>{// in order to use await in checkifexist
//your rest of the code.
let result=await checkifexist();// waiting for db result
async function checkifexist(){//your awaited code.}
console.log(result);
});
```